# Issue with installing python3-devel gcc

Tags: apt, python, gcc, python3

I am trying to install `python3-devel` gcc, but whenever I do that it tells me

> E:Unable to locate package python3-devel

Is there a way to fix this issue?
The commands that I am doing is

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev gcc
sudo apt install python3-devel gcc
```

When I run the first line I get the following:

[image: First line of code message]

and

[image: Second line of code message]

Comment: There is [no `python3-devel` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=python3-devel&searchon=names) in Ubuntu. But [`python3-dev` package exists](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=python3-dev&searchon=names). If you are trying to follow some guide, then try to read it again with Debian and/or Ubuntu specifics.

Comment: `python3-devel` is a [Linux Redhat](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#id1) dependency.